# How to bind a form in SAPUI5?

Tags: sapui5

I was trying to figure out how to bind a simple form in UI5 (not a list) so I can submit to my oData backend . How do I do that with a simple form?

Here is my controller code (if I were to do in a List) - But I have no clue how to deal with a Form:

```
var oList = this.byId("addapp"),
                oBinding = oList.getBinding("items"),
                // Create a new entry through the table's list binding
                oContext = oBinding.create({
                    "application_id": 0,
                    "product_name_short": 'Test',
                });
```

This is what I have tried so far, but I got undefined value:

```
var x =this.getView().byId("addapp").getBinding("items");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have set a model to your view, you can bind an existing object to a view using [Element.bindElement](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.ui.core.Element/methods/bindElement):

```
this.getView().byId("addapp").bindElement("/path/to/your/object");
```

If you want to use a temporary model (to use the data once you click "add" or something similar):

```
onInit: function () {
    // Initial values of the form
    this.getView().setModel(new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel({
        property1: "",
        property2: "",
        property3: ""
    }), "newEntry");

    // Bind the form to the json model
    this.getView().byId("addapp").bindElement("newEntry>/");
},

onAddButtonClick: function() {
    // Get the form values
    var newEntry = this.getView().getModel("newEntry").getData();

    // Use the OData model to create a new entity
    var oDataModel = ...;
    oDataModel.create("/path/to/your/entityset", newEntry, {
        success: function() {
            // entity was created
        }
    });
}
```